# Android In App Purchase Order Status Chargeable

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, status

I have an in app purchase for a managed product via Google's In App Billing.

Orders are coming through however I'm seeing order status Chargeable in Wallet Merchant Center.

The odd thing is that the Order Status is Chargeable, however Delivery Status says Delivered.

What does Chargeable mean exactly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just had a talk with their customer support. According to them, every order is put in the "Chargeable" state when it is being reviewed by them.

It stays in this state for a period of 6 hours after which it becomes "Payable".

Comment: And should we consider valid the purchase ou wait for the state to change in order the user starts using it ?

Comment: For that, you need to use the developer APIs to verify the purchases later and check for cancellations.